# How to fix problems converting string to datetime with Python / Django?

Tags: python, django

I have the following two imports:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime as dt
```

If I try

```
date = dt.datetime.strptime(data['Time'][i],"%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

I get the following error: AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'endswith'

If I try

```
date = dt.strptime(data['Time'][i],"%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

I get the following error: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

I am using Python 3.8.3 with Django 3 - why is it behaving like this and how can I fix this?

Comment: what is i. are you iterating thru the list?

Comment: try pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format="%Y-%m-%d")

Comment: data is a pandas dataframe, i is an index.
print(data['Time'][i]) results in 2019-01-17 and 
print(type(data['Time'][i])) results in <class 'str'>

Comment: are you doing a for loop to do this? can you please share a few more lines of code. I think you can just apply it directly to the whole column than a specific row

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that `data[‘Time’][i]` is indeed a string? It looks like `strptime` got a `datetime.date` object.

Comment: yes. print(data['Time'][i]) results in 2019-01-17 and print(type(data['Time'][i])) results in <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to convert a specific cell (row,column) to date format.

Here's how you will do it for the whole column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01-01-2021','01-02-2021','01-03-2021']})
print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

The output of this will be:

Created a string of dates. dtype is object

```
         date
0  01-01-2021
1  01-02-2021
2  01-03-2021

date    object
dtype: object
```

Post conversion, the dtype has changed to datetime. Note that I didn't specify the format. Pandas is smart enough to figure that out from the string.

```
        date
0 2021-01-01
1 2021-01-02
2 2021-01-03

date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```